# Vhs-viewhelper and for loop

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to get the next news item from within current news item.
Using the extension "vhs" and tx_news.

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
    Current title: {newsItem.title}
    <v:variable.set name="nextNews" value="{v:iterator.next(needle: newsItem, haystack: news)}"/>
    Next title: {nextNews.title}
</f:for>
```

It will print correct titles once. Then the loop ends abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set an condition to catch up the last iteration because there is no more "next" news.

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
  Current title: {newsItem.title}
  <f:if condition="{iterator.isLast}">
    <f:else>
      <v:variable.set name="nextNews" value="{v:iterator.next(needle: newsItem, haystack: news)}"/>
      Next title: {nextNews.title}
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: Tried it, but no change.

Comment: Please try to activate the displaying of errors and maybe set your ip to the devIpMask in the install tool. Without any error we can only guess what it can be.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem yesterday with setting a variable in a for-loop. 
I solved the problem by clearing that variable. 
In your case i would try the following:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
<v:variable.set name="nextNews" value="" />
Current title: {newsItem.title}
<v:variable.set name="nextNews" value="{v:iterator.next(needle: newsItem, haystack: news)}"/>
Next title: {nextNews.title}
</f:for>
```

That one clears the variable before setting it (again).
At least i would try that :)